# “Congratulations on …” or “congratulations for …”?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

While I was chatting with one of my friends on Facebook, I wrote this to him after he was selected in a on-campus recruitment drive by the company TCS from our college:

> Congratulation *on* being selected in [TCS](http://www.tcs.com/).

Then I thought, should it be "on" instead of "for"? I felt perplexed. I thought if I said *on* it would mean "Congratulation *on the occasion of* being selected in TCS." and if I say "for" it would mean "Congratulation *for* being selected in TCS." So is it understandable to use "on"? Or must I use "for" here?

Comment: I have no problem with the preposition, but I would probably use the plural: _congratulations_.

Comment: If I were to have a problem with a preposition in this sentence it would be *in* with *TCS*.  (But perhaps that's because I haven't any idea what TCS is.)  *Congratulations on* is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, [TCS](http://www.tcs.com) is an IT giant company in India. :) And about the plural, yes, it should be _Congratulations_.

Comment: Thank you.  In that case, the preposition with *TCS* might also be any one of several other prepositions, depending on the occasion for the selection: *for* if the selectee was chosen to join TCS; *at* if the selectee is currently an employee and the selector was also at TCS; *from* if the selectee is a TCS employee and the selector was someone outside the company.  (There are other possibilities as well.)

Comment: There are **two** major problems with the sentence, but **on** isn't one of them. It should be ***Congratulations** on being selected **by** TCS*. Feasibly ***for** TCS*, but given TCS is a company, I assume TCS itself made the selection - ***for*** would be more appropriate if it was something like *selected **for** the award*, where the award itself didn't actually do the selecting.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, You should have added it as an answer. Very detailed and informative.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, TCS came for on-campus recruitment and the students were selected by TCS through a standard selection procedure.

Comment: @Mistu4u: Since you just wrote *by TCS* there, why did you write ***in** TCS* in the question text?

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Well you know, by _by_ I mean the selection was conducted by TCS and by _in_ I mean they are selected within/into TCS.

Comment: @Mistu4u: Sorry - neither *in* nor *within* are grammatically meaningful in that context. Worry about that crucial fact and why you don't see why. Forget about *congratulations on/for*, since either is perfectly grammatical and meaningful (it just so happens one is more common than the other).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Maybe it is the difference between usages of _in_ in English and my mother tongue that is creating the confusion. However I would certainly abide by rules of English, when talking in English. My friend who I chatted with is a native here, So he got my sense. :)

Comment: @Mistu4u: My point is the difference between *congratulations **on*** and ***for*** is entirely arbitrary - it means nothing, so the best you can do is *remember* that we normally use ***on***. But knowing it won't help you learn anything else about the *principles* of English. But there's a *reason* why we say *selected **for*** rather than ***in*** here. Understanding why will probably help you with other aspects of the language.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I should understand this fact clearly as it can create serious confusion later. What happened in the scenario is, TCS a company came to our campus (By _TCS came_ I mean recruiters of TCS who are also employee there) and after a standard selection procedure they selected some students from our college who are fresher i.e. they just passed out after completion of their graduation. So what should I say **Selected _in_ TCS** or **Selected _by_ TCS**?

Comment: @Mistu4u: I can only suppose you're thinking in terms of *congratulations on [being selected just now as someone who later on will be] **in** TCS*. The only other construction where you'd normally use ***in*** is something like *congratulations on getting the highest score **in** the semifinals*, where you "achieve something" [with]in the context of some particular event/contest/selection process. In your context, *as you yourself wrote*, the important fact is that selection was made ***by*** TCS (not that later you'll be ***in*** it). And TCS isn't the name of an "event/selection process".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using *on* here is perfectly idiomatic. And it's quoted as an example [in a respected dictionary](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/congratulation):

> *noun*
>   (**congratulations**)
>   words expressing one’s praise for an achievement or good wishes on a special occasion:
>   *our congratulations to the winners*
>
> [*as exclamation*]:
>   *congratulations on a job well done!*
>
> - [*mass noun*] the action of expressing congratulations:
>     *he began pumping the hand of his son in congratulation*

*Congratulations for* would be understood. [Google Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=congratulations+for%2Ccongratulations+on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) shows that *on* is far more common than *for,* though.

[As an aside, *in TCS* sounds odd, but I've no idea what TCS is, so it may be fine.]

Comment: [TCS](http://www.tcs.com) is name of a company.